# What are the largest airports in terms of size, gates, and stands?

Tags: airport

What is the largest airport in terms of:

1. Size of developed area?
2. Size of all terminal area?
3. Total number of gates?
4. Total number of gates + remote stands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. According to [InsiderMonkey](http://www.insidermonkey.com/blog/the-10-biggest-airports-in-the-world-334297/) DFW ([Dallas/Fort Worth International Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas/Fort_Worth_International_Airport)) is the largest at 4360 hectares.
2. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_buildings_in_the_world) DXB ([Dubai International Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai_International_Airport)) has the largest terminal in terms of floorspace at 1,713,000 m2 (18,440,000 sq ft) with a volume of approximately 10.0 million m³ (360 million cu ft)
3. According to [this forum](http://forum.skyscraperpage.com/showthread.php?t=204975) ATL ([Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartsfield%E2%80%93Jackson_Atlanta_International_Airport)) has 206 gates
4. Can't find this one

Comment: Depending on how you define "developed area", [Edwards Air Force Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_Air_Force_Base) could surpass DFW.  It's got a lot of runways, and some of them are rather large (eg. 17/35 is about 400 hectares for the runway surface alone).

Comment: In addition to its massive number of gates, ATL is also the world's largest by passenger throughput and by flight operations.

Comment: @Mark - "developed area" of Edwards typically does not include the dry lakebeds and their runways (which are marked more for convenience than anything; Edwards is the primary government test-flight facility in part because the lakebed is flat enough to land practically anywhere). Being fair to commercial installations, areas of the base that don't have a counterpart on commercial installations, such as barracks/base housing, should be excluded as well. That dramatically reduces Edwards' "developed size".

Answer (score 6):

I nominate [Davis Monthan Air Force Base](https://www.google.nl/maps/@32.153016,-110.8283374,1761m/data=!3m1!1e3) as the winner in category 4. Not for the number of gates, it is the number of remote stands that does it.

Comment: [In English](https://goo.gl/maps/KmxOF) for us Americanian types.

Comment: most of those planes looks half demoed

Comment: @ratchetfreak they are...

Comment: the boneyard counts as a bunch of remote stands? that's like saying a cemetery counts as housing.